# Authoritative list of Bitcoin resources?

Tags: community

Has any website compiled a reasonably authoritative and trustworthy list of Bitcoin resources? I'm building an appendix for my course and I'd like to see if I missed anything.

https://www.udemy.com/bitcoin-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-crypto/

Edit:

To address Nick's concerns, let me clarify the purpose of this question. I am not asking for your favorite Bitcoin links. I am asking for authoritative and trustworthy lists of Bitcoin resources. For example: https://www.spendbitcoins.com/places/ is a reasonably trustworthy list of bitcoin commerce sites.

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It's a legitimate question to ask if someone created a Bitcoin link bank? The Bitcoin wiki has a link bank. Should we downvote their efforts?

Comment: Because this essentially asking, 'What links do you thing are good' which will provoke discussion.

Comment: I'm asking for link banks. I.e. lists people have compiled containing links relevant to the Bitcoin

Comment: Okay, so you're asking for links to links. How is that better?

Comment: Links to websites that have taken the time to vet and organize links. And yes it is better because I'm building an appendix with them after I take the time to vet them myself.

Comment: And did you get that interview I sent you?

Comment: @CharlesHoskinson I changed the language a bit to make answers a matter of fact rather than opinion.  Personally I'm voting to leave this open--this is an important, factual question with value for future users based on a real-world need.

Comment: And thanks for the edit. I'll be offering a bounty on this one soon.

Comment: @CharlesHoskinson I'm sorry if you feel that  I have something against you personally. If you'd like to discuss a way I could moderate that'd be less abrasive, you can email me or open a chat room with me.

Comment: Oh Nick, you know I'm just giving you a hard time. I'm too lovable to hate :)

Comment: Mods should at least post a comment after downvoting instead of forcing users to ask why the downvote. This is the only SE site where people get randomly downvoted without having any clue why.

Comment: Nick and I have a unique relationship. It's ok. This community has lots of interesting and lovable personalities. And I will shamelessly promote my course: https://www.udemy.com/bitcoin-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-crypto/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four really authoritative places for Bitcoin-related information that I can think of.

1. The [Bitcoin.org](http://bitcoin.org) homepage, which is managed by the core Bitcoin developers. All names listed on that site and references made can be considered authoritative.
2. [BitcoinTalk.org](http://bitcointalk.org), this was the homepage for the Bitcoin community from the start. Most of the first ideas were created here and still this is the best place to get information from other authoritative people strongly related to Bitcoin.
3. [The Bitcoin Wiki](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Main_Page), were you can find all technical specifications of the protocol as well as more basic information about how to buy, sell or use bitcoins. The wiki is maintained by the developers as well as insiders that helped shaping the protocol.
4. [Bitcoin on GitHub](https://github.com/bitcoin), were development of the main client happens and all changes to the protocol are implemented for the first time. You can also find a link to this place on the Bitcoin homepage.

Answer (score 1):

The most comprehensive list I have come across is [Stuff Exists](http://stuffexists.com/bitcoin/). I have not personally checked each link but it will give a good basis on where to pull a list of sites from.

Answer (score 1):

This one is a good resource, and trusted http://bitcoin.bitshare.cm

Comment: Your answer offers only one addition instead of creating an encompassing answer. It would be better if you created a complete up-to-date answer that also added the resources linked in older answers that are still relevant and any other new ones that have cropped up in the last half year. As it is, it looks like promotion of a specific service that you might be affiliated with.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest https://github.com/coinpride/CryptoList

It is the most advanced crypto links list because it is opensourced and thus contains only the freshest links.